# Task Scheduler Fails .Net 4.5 Console Application

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, scheduled-tasks

I have a .Net 4.5 Console Application written in C# that makes a call to SQL using Entity Framework 6.1.3 and generates a PDF.  The application runs fine if you run the executable but it fails when ran through Task Scheduler.  It will only run on Task Scheduler with option "Run only when user is logged in" I need it to run when not logged in.

What I did to test the executable in Task Scheduler was to mock the data gets called from Entity Framework and the application worked just fine so something tells me that Task Scheduler did not like my Entity Framework call.  Yet I have other Schedule Tasks Running using Entity Framework.. Not sure what the problem is. Below is one the error seen in Windows Log.

> Application: CreatePDFFile.exe
>   Framework Version: v4.0.30319
>   Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
>   Exception Info: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
>   Stack:
>      at System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryAction`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].PerformAction(System.__Canon)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabaseAction(System.Action`1)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabase()
>      at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.get_ObjectContext()
>      at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.ExecuteSqlQuery[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]](System.String, System.Nullable`1<Boolean>, System.Object[])
>      at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.ExecuteSqlQueryAsIEnumerator[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]](System.String, System.Nullable`1, System.Object[])
>      at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.ExecuteSqlQuery(System.Type, System.String, System.Nullable`1<Boolean>, System.Object[])
>      at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalSqlNonSetQuery.GetEnumerator()
>      at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbRawSqlQuery`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].GetEnumerator()
>      at System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].MoveNext()
>      at System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]..ctor(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<System.__Canon>)
>      at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1)
>      at Repository.MyRepository.GetData(System.String, System.String, System.String, Int32)

Comment: What is the `SqlException`'s `InnerException` property?  That'll tell you what the issue is.  I'm guessing its unable to connect to the database as a system user.

Comment: Do you use Windows auth in connection string or SQL server auth. It might be, that system user is not allowed to connect to SQL Server, while user that is logged on, can (that's why you probably get an error on db initialization)

Answer (score 0):

I am using SQL Authentication.  I added a try catch error and I get this:

> Login failed: The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used
>   with Windows Authentication.

After looking at my connection string, I realized that I had copied the connectionstring from my PC to the server and replaced the data source but not the credentials....So its resolved.